How to write boot persistent files outside the document root with a PHP web application?
The systemd PrivateTmp option for a php-fpm service affects write access to files outside the document root.
e.g. Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9 and PHP 8.2.13
For example, if var/tmp/myApp (say) is used for temporary files that are required to outlive a reboot, write access is prevented if true and permitted otherwise.
The systemd manual describes how a process specific subtree is used and mounted instead of a vanilla /tmp.  It also refers to var/tmp, but I haven't seen any evidence that this happens.  If it did, wouldn’t this be a contradiction – because /tmp is cleared on boot?
Because I wish all files inside the document root to be read-only for reasons of security, how should php.ini and the php-fpm service be configured to permit write access to other paths, such as /var/tmp/myApp with PrivateTmp = true?

Isn't this what the database is for?

"Temporary files that must persist" Then those are, by definition, not temporary files. You should stop referring to them as such, and not put them in the systemd-managed tempfile locations because they will correctly be deleted during reboots and other operations.


temporary files that are required to outlive a reboot

This is contradictory. If you need files to outlive a reboot, then, by definition, they're not temporary.
The general mechanism you'd use to solve this issue is to have your document root one level down from your project root, and then use a project-specific "temporary" directory at the project root. For example, consider the directory layout of this project:
/path/to/project
├── log
│   └── 20240904.log
├── public
│   ├── images
│   │   └── logo.png
│   ├── index.php
│   └── js
│       └── app.js
├── src
│   ├── Model
│   │   └── User.php
│   └── Service
│       └── Foo.php
└── var
    └── cache
        └── abcde

If you now point your document root at the public subdir rather than the /path/to/project dir, then the web server process will have access to only the files below that point, which are only the files that will be directly served to clients. Everything else, including PHP source, lives outside the document root, and the web server doesn't even know of its existence.
But the php-fpm process runs (should, at least) as a different user than the web server process, so you can now control the access separately. For example, the web server user would only have read access to public while the php-fpm user would have write access to var/cache. This would allow your PHP code to arbitrarily read/write files in var/cache that would survive reboots, but the web client would never be able to directly request those files via some url like http://yoursite.com/var/cache/abcde.
